# In react.js with chart.js, I can't access to my data in a componant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have a simple chart with chart.js in React.js app. I would like to acces at my data in my component. For create a simple button to add data in my chart. But he send me an error. Could you please help me and explain me to acces to my data in an other componant. Thx you so much.

My componant BarChart.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2'

const BarChart = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Bar 
                data={{
                    labels: ['Paris', 'Boston', 'Berlin', 'Dublin', 'Barcelone', 'Lisbonne'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Populations en millions',
                        data: [2.2, 0.7, 3.8, 1.4, 1.6, 0.6],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                }}
            height={500}
            width={500}
            options={{
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default BarChart
```

My componant ButtonChart.js

```
import React from "react"
import BarChart from "./BarChart";

const ButtonChart = () => {
    return (
        <div className="inputBox">
            <input type="number" className="inputAdd" placeholder="Valeur" id="inputData"/>
            <input type="text" className="inputAdd" placeholder="Année" id="label"/>
            <button onClick={updateChart()} id="insertData">Ajouter une donnée</button>
        </div>
    )
}

function updateChart() {
    const inputData = document.getElementById('inputData');
    BarChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(inputData.value);
}

export default ButtonChart
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVswP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing `BarChart.data` seems wrong as, `BarChart` is basically a functional React component.

What you want is probably this:

1. You have a `data` array.
2. You want to show that `data` in a `BarChart`
3. You want to give a `button` to the user such that when user clicks that button, a new row is added into that `data` array.
4. And when that `data` array changes, you want the `BarChart` to refresh and display the updated `data` array.

If this is the case, then I would recommend checking the [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in the React docs. It is pretty much the same use case here. You have a single data source shared across 2 components.

Also, check the usage of React hooks for checking state usage: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Here is a pseudocode you can try:

```
ParentComponent = () => {

    // 1. Create your data state here using React Hooks
    const [data, setData] = useState([someInitialData]);
    
    return (
        <div>
            // 2. BarChart now relies on the data in the state
            //    Whenever the data updates, the chart refreshes
            <BarChart data={data}/>
            // 3. Pass setData to the component and trigger it with the 
            //    button's onClick handler
            <ButtonChart updateData={setData}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need to do. I will try your code. Need I to use usestate for this exemple ? That right ? thank you